# Lock screen and take a photo by button

Tags: camera

I bought a waterproof case when I put my mobile phone in and put it under water, so the water pressure will cause other applications or some settings to switch on the screen and I can not take a photo. When I use the "touch lock" application, the camera does not work on the button again, again the button is used to control the volume. Is there an application that locks the screen but lets me take a picture using the button?

Comment: It is not the water pressure, those waterproof cases allow using the screen outside of the water, therefore they have to be electrical conductive. Unfortunately water itself is also electrical conductive and so the screen can not detect your touches as there is not difference between your finger and the water around. You need a camera app that allows to take a picture only by pressing one or more hardware keys.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation And do you know any such application, pls?

Comment: 3rd Party app like Macrodroid should do it

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how to Macrodroid use :/ seems complicated and do not see any condition that can help me :/

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest looking into dive.plus...the community there could also give you some great additional tips. The app is very good with all aspects of underwater photography. The app is known also as Dive+ and is available widely.